# How to receive an incoming phone call automatically in android

Tags: android, telephonymanager

What I want is... when an incoming call is coming it will answered automatically.
Here is my code but its not working.

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                try {
            System.out.println("Receiver start");
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);

            String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

                Toast.makeText(context, "Incoming Call State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing State Number is -" + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
            if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call Received State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Call Idle State", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I hope in the RINGING function I need to do some code. But I am not getting the proper ans so I post this. Please Developers Help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't do Toast in a Receiver because there's no UI active and the receiver is not running in the UI thread. Instead, you can create a notification. If your app is on top when the call comes in, you can register a broadcastreceiver in your activity, and handle the call there.

Comment: I want to receive the incoming call by a button what I use in my app. Not the default "Answer" Button Using.
Can you please Guide.
Thanks